# PyInstaller: Syntax error with --add-binary option, even though it follows the documentation

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Encountering a syntax error with PyInstaller's --add-binary option:

```
pyinstaller --add-binary "ViGEmClient.dll" pg.py --onefile
```

Error:

```
pyinstaller: error: argument --add-binary: Wrong syntax, should be --add-binary=SOURCE:DEST
```

Using PyInstaller version [6.3.0]. Is there something I'm missing in the syntax?

Comment: Try `pyinstaller --add-binary "ViGEmClient.dll:ViGEmClient.dll" pg.py --onefile`